# How to obtain UITextFields from a singleton

Tags: iphone

I need just four parameters to drive the calculations in three view controllers. The parameters come from four UITextFields in the first view. I'm not using global variables but have developed a singleton class to enable the parameters to be available to each controller. I can reference the variables OK in the controllers but I don't know how to initialize them. I've obtained the variables from the first viewcontroller through a windows I developed with IB but can't seem to find a way to get these initialized in the singleton.

Help and guidance gratefully appreciated.

```
//
//  GlobalParameters.h
//  ProjectEstimator
//
//  This is a SINGLETON class used to handle global parameters for use in the various view controllers.
//
//
//
//  Created by Frank Williamson on 10/06/2010.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GlobalParameters : NSObject {

// Place any "global" variables here

//  float *processes;
//  float *entities;
//  float *transactions;
//  float *users;



    IBOutlet UITextField *noOfProcesses;
    IBOutlet UITextField *noOfEntityClusters;
    IBOutlet UITextField *noOfTransactions;
    IBOutlet UITextField *noOfUserArea;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *noOfProcesses;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *noOfEntityClusters;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *noOfTransactions;
@property (retain, nonatomic) UITextField *noOfUserArea;

// message from which our instance is obtained    
+ (GlobalParameters *)sharedInstance;    
@end

//
//  GlobalParameters.m
//  ProjectEstimator        Singleton for handling (global) parameters.
//
//  Created by Frank Williamson on 10/06/2010.
//

#import "GlobalParameters.h"


@implementation GlobalParameters;

@synthesize     noOfProcesses;
@synthesize     noOfEntityClusters;
@synthesize     noOfTransactions;
@synthesize     noOfUserArea;

+ (GlobalParameters *)sharedInstance{

    // the instance of this class is stored here        
    static GlobalParameters *noOfProcesses = nil;
    static GlobalParameters *noOfEntityClusters = nil;
    static GlobalParameters *noOfTransactions = nil;
    static GlobalParameters *noOfUserArea = nil;

    // check to see if an instance already exists

    if (nil == noOfProcesses) {
        noOfProcesses  = [[[self class] alloc] init];

        // **How to I initialize UITextFields from a ViewController in here??**
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return noOfProcesses;

    if (nil == noOfEntityClusters) {
        noOfEntityClusters  = [[[self class] alloc] init];

        // **How to I initialize UITextFields from a ViewController in here??**
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return noOfEntityClusters;  

    if (nil == noOfTransactions) {
        noOfTransactions  = [[[self class] alloc] init];

        // **How to I initialize UITextFields from a ViewController in here??**
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return noOfTransactions;

    if (nil == noOfUserArea) {
        noOfUserArea  = [[[self class] alloc] init];

        // **How to I initialize UITextFields from a ViewController in here??**
    }
    // return the instance of this class
    return noOfUserArea;        
}
@end
```

Comment: Use the "101010" button to format code blocks

Comment: Um, how in the world is execution **ever** going to reach `if(nil==noOfEntityClusters)...`

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of things here I would change. First, I wouldn't create a "Globals" class. Second, if I did, would never store `UIView` objects in class designed to be a "model". Third, if I absolutely needed to implement a singleton, I would follow the [design pattern](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SingletonDesignPattern) for Cocoa.

> I need just four parameters to drive the calculations in three view controllers.

And at that point I recommend you throw out this class entirely and re-think your design problem. Is it simply that you need to store four `NSString` parameters (or `NSNumber`s or `NSInteger`s or `float`s or...)? If so, it's complete overkill to store the parameters inside a view class. Just create a simple class to store the parameters, whose header would look something like:

```
@interface MyParameters : NSObject
{
    NSString* someString;
    NSNumber* someNumber;
    NSInteger someInteger;
    float     someFloat;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* someString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* someNumber;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger someInteger;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float     someFloat;

@end
```

I would instantiate an object of this class either in my application delegate or in my root view controller, and then I would pass it along to any other view controllers that needed access to it. Finally, I would use [Key-Value Observing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) so every view controller that needs it will get automatic updates to any changes to the parameters.